# JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence' not found error from kundera 2.7.1

Tags: jboss7.x, kundera

I am new to jBoss (7.1) and Kundera (2.7.1) and I'm working on a project and I want to use Cassandra dataSource  implementing JPA using Kundera. my persistence.xml is as follows:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"<br/>
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence<br/>
    http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"<br/>
    version="1.0"><br/>
    <persistence-unit name="cassandra_pu"><br/>
        <provider>com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence</provider><br/>
        <properties><br/>
            <property name="kundera.nodes" value="localhost" /><br/>
            <property name="kundera.port" value="9160" />
            <property name="kundera.keyspace" value="ech" />
            <property name="kundera.dialect" value="cassandra" />
            <property name="kundera.client.lookup.class" value="com.impetus.client.cassandra.thrift.ThriftClientFactory" />
            <property name="kundera.cache.provider.class" value="com.impetus.kundera.cache.ehcache.EhCacheProvider"/>
            <property name="kundera.cache.config.resource" value="/ehcache-test.xml" />
            <!--  <property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
   </persistence>
```

and my applicationContext.xml is as follows

```
    ?<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <bean id="personDAO" class="com.impetus.kundera.examples.spring.PersonDAO">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
    </bean>     
    <bean id="entityManagerFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="cassandra_pu" />
    </bean> 
</beans>
```

when I remove "jboss.as.jpa.managed = false" property from persistence.xml, i am receiving **JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence' not found** error and if I place "jboss.as.jpa.managed=false" property, i am endup with **No persistence unit with name 'cassandra_pu' found** error

Complete trace for both errors:

No persistence unit with name 'cassandra_pu' found  --- persistence.xml contains  property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"

> Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No persistence unit with name 'cassandra_pu' found
>     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.persistenceunit.DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.obtainPersistenceUnitInfo(DefaultPersistenceUnitManager.java:566) [spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.determinePersistenceUnitInfo(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:308) [spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:260) [spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:310) [spring-orm-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1541) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
>     at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1479) [spring-beans-3.2.4.RELEASE.jar:3.2.4.RELEASE]
>     ... 20 more

JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence' not found   --- remove from persistence.xml - property name="jboss.as.jpa.managed" value="false"

> Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: JBAS011466: PersistenceProvider 'com.impetus.kundera.KunderaPersistence' not found
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.lookupProvider(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:560)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deployPersistenceUnit(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:297)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.addPuService(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:260)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.handleEarDeployment(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:218)
>     at org.jboss.as.jpa.processor.PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.deploy(PersistenceUnitDeploymentProcessor.java:121)
>     at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentUnitPhaseService.start(DeploymentUnitPhaseService.java:116) [jboss-as-server-7.1.3.Final-redhat-4.jar:7.1.3.Final-redhat-4]
>     ... 5 more

jars in ear is

```
cassandra-connection-pool-0.7.1.jar
commons-lang-2.4.jar
commons-logging-1.1.1.jar
commons-pool-1.2.jar
guava-14.0.1.jar
hibernate-commons-annotations-4.0.2.Final.jar
hibernate-core-4.2.3.Final.jar
javassist-3.15.0-GA.jar
jta-1.1.jar
jts-1.11.jar
kundera-cassandra-2.7.1.jar
kundera-core-2.7.1.jar
lucene-core-3.5.0.jar
persistence-api-1.0.jar
slf4j-api-1.7.2.jar
spring-beans-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-context-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-core-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-jdbc-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-orm-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
spring-tx-3.0.0.RELEASE.jar
```

**P.S - I dont have any jpa related folders under \JBOSS_HOME>\modules\org\apache  and  my persistence.xml is present under MyEAR.ear>META-INF>persistence.xml (along with application.xml, jboss-deployment-structure.xml and MANIFEST.MF)**

Hope I've provided all the necessary informations. I am stuck from entire day at this. Any help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This should help you out.  please have a look at https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/390  https://github.com/impetus-opensource/Kundera/issues/180